# Issues Angular Restangular save and update operations

Tags: angularjs, restangular, restheart

I decided to take my project in the Restangular, but I have some problems in the SAVE and UPDATE operations.

I use the API restheart with mongodb.

In SAVE in my case, I'm saving a New Post, and when by chance I make any changes, it saves a new post out instead of updating it.

UPDATE on, I can update the first instance, for example, make a change in title and saved, it updated if I update again .. generates this error:

PUT http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/portfolio/55ef4b15ef862e8f7316cbf1 412 (Precondition Failed)
Follow my resource and code:

```
Restangular.all($scope.section).getList($scope.query).then(function(res){
    $scope.items = res;
});
```

my SAVE:

```
// create new object item
$scope.item = Restangular.one($scope.section);

// save object
$scope.addItem = function(){
    $scope.item.save().then(function(){
            toast.msgToast($scope.section + ' ...item criado!');
    }, function(err){
        toast.msgToast($scope.section + ' ...ocorreu um erro ao criar o item!');
    });
};
```

my UPDATE:

```
$scope.updateItem = function(){
        $scope.item.save().then(function(){
            toast.msgToast($scope.section+ ' #' +$scope.item._id.$oid+ ' ....Atualizado!');
        });
    };

    $scope.loadItem = function(){
        Restangular.one($scope.section, $stateParams.id).get().then(function(item) {
            $scope.item = item;
        });
    };
```

Comment: Why dont you rather use the `post()` and `put()` restangular functions explicitly rather than the `save()` method?

Comment: Post or put, the same error, i thing this problem in Etag response..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RESTHeart, POST and PUT are upsert operations, i.e. they create a resource if it does not exist or updates it.

The point here is about the _id:

- In PUT operations, the document id is given by the URI /db/collection/id_of_document (more information on URI format in the official documentation [here](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/ToCM))
- In POST operations, the *_id* property *can* be specified in the json payload. If it is not specified, a new document gets created and the automatically generated *_id* (of type ObjectId) is returned via the *Location* response header. If the *_id* is specified, the POST will result in an update given that a document with that *_id* already exists.

In your case, on fist POST (that creates the document), you need to get the *Location* response header with the URI of the created post resource and reload it via a GET operation; further POST with this data (that now contains the generated *_id*) will result in an update.

In any case, when your are doing a POST, PATCH, PUT or DELETE operation on an existing resource, you need to pass the ETag via the *If-Match* request header. You can find more information in the [ETag](https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/hICM) section of the official documentation, including an example with AngularJs.

More, there is a complete example of a web application using RESTHeart, AngluarJs and Restangular on github: [restheart-notes-example](https://github.com/softinstigate/restheart-notes-example).

Have a look at the [notes.js](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart-notes-example/blob/master/app/scripts/controllers/notes.js) controller, where you'll find all the logic to create, update and delete documents.

Comment: Thx for response, but the example of SoftInstigate, dont work for me. I change my code, follow the example and got an error: Error: data._id is undefined

Comment: One thing I have ever seen , is that not with POST or SAVE , the server sends me an answer , because I could give a get with the id in the response of creation, but does not return anything.

Comment: If the POST or SAVE (PUT) created the document, you got a response. This includes the Location response header that is the URI of the new document, that includes the document id and also the ETag. You need either to reload the document (via that URI) or manually add the _id (note that this is { '_id': { '$oid': '<STRING_ID_IN_URI>' } }

Comment: Also look at [app.js](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart-notes-example/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js) in the same example. Here we configure Restangular via RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
                    id: "_id.$oid",
                    etag: "_etag.$oid",
                    selfLink: "_links['self'].href"
                });